# Google App Engine URL Handler Error While Running

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, yaml

This is my app.yml file

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.py
```

The hello.py is located at the same directory as the app.yml file.

When I run the app I get this error:

```
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    secure=default 
    static_files=None 
    application_readable=None 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    require_matching_file=None 
    static_dir=None 
    redirect_http_response_code=None 
    http_headers=None 
    url=/.* 
    script=None 
    upload=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    expiration=None 
    position=None 
    login=optional 
    mime_type=None
    >
  in "C:\Users\***\Desktop\app\app.yaml", line 8, column 1
2016-03-01 11:36:12 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I thought it was spacing that was the issue so I added two spaces after script but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I suspect the complaint is about the `.py` suffix of `hello.py`, don't you mean `hello.app` instead (which would require the corresponding `hello.py` file containing the app code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition of your handler in app.yaml to:

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.app
```

Pay close attention to the `script:` property. It should be pointing to your `WSGIApplication`, which for the example above is defined within the `app` variable.